# Entity Framework targetting wrong database. (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

While this wpf project runs very stabil for the past 2 years, i now get a EF problem stating "CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'."

All the migrations are in the _MigrationHistory table:
[image]

and nothing has changed from the config.

The app.config:

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=********.com;Database=******;Integrated Security=False;Initial Catalog=*******;User ID=*******;Password=********" />

  </connectionStrings>
```

the last action was a publish to a click once folder online.

I allready reinstalled EF 6.1.3 => no success

Please help we with debugging this issue, i don't know where to look first...

a simple get-migrations doesn't see the migrations.

PM> Get-Migrations

Retrieving migrations that have been applied to the target database.

No migrations have been applied to the target database.

PM>

Comment: talk to your database admin? Possibly permissions changed?

Comment: when i connect to the sql everything seems fine. no problem loggin in.

Comment: When i use a local SQL server, and do a update-database everything seems to be working fine. The 2 _MigrationHistory tables look identical. still, online database won't work. is there somewhere else that EF keeps track of the pending changes ?

Comment: Have you tried to roll back migrations to a certain point and then reapply them?

Comment: This issue was an DB rights problem issued by the hosting. There mistake, many apologies.